# From content scripts, can I make an ajax call to a REST API on hosted on my server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After reading blogs and some stackoverflow answers while building a chrome extension, I had for some reason thought that we cannot make an ajax call to a REST API hosted on server that comes under another domain than the hosted page. Is this correct? While developing my extension, I mistakenly made a call from a content script on clicking a button on my extension UI (UI is injected into the DOM using content script). I did not ran into any error. Everything went smooth. The host page in my test case is infact a page from stack overflow, and the REST API is hosted on my **localhost**. Could it be because the api was on local host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Chrome [XHR documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr):

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

Furthermore, from the [Content Script documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> Content scripts can also make cross-site XMLHttpRequests to the same sites as their parent extensions [...]

So the only thing you need is to add your API endpoint to host permissions in the manifest:

```
"permissions" : [
  "*://api.example.com/*"
]
```

Comment: Cant forget about that header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` will be required in response from `api.example.com` if script will be running with pages from other domains than `example.com`.

Comment: @yergo False. That's exactly what host permissions allow you to ignore. If the server returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, they are not needed.

Comment: Have you tested that? I have tested that two weeks ago an I happen to be required to send that header anyway. Edit: may be because I have injected my script into webpage itself.

Comment: Did you have extension host permissions properly declared? And yes, I'm using cross-origin XHR in my extensions that would otherwise fail due to this.

Comment: So with the permission defined for my API host server I can communicate with specifically this server. But just to understand better, what is happening in the case local host? I have not declared anything for local host but still things are working. Is that an exception?

Comment: Oh I missed out on this! I have "http://*/*" under permissions in my manifest. This would probably let me talk to any server outside. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Assuming @Xan answer, yes as long as `http://`. According to my comment I must agree with Xan, that Allow-Origin header may not be required, because my script that was crushing w/o it, is injected into page during page load, and runs in its context, what mostly does not match your question. Excuse me :)